# How to get selected text using javascript on vscode.dev website?

Tags: javascript, dom

Short summary: `getSelection().toString()` behaves unexpectedly on https://vscode.dev.

Detailed question:

I need to write a javascript script which gets the text selected by the user. Usually I do it with `getSelection().toString()`, but for some reason this does not work for https://vscode.dev (online version of VSCode editor). Instead of copying all the selected text, the code above evaluates to a shortened version of the selected text, with an ellipsis in the middle. For example, if I select this text...

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
```

then `getSelection().toString()` evaluates to

```
'1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n…21\n22\n23\n24\n25\n26\n27\n28\n29\n30'
```

that is it looses some text in the middle.

[image]

How to work around it and get all the selected text?

P.S. In case you ask, the Chrome console did not shorten this text, it was shortened by javascript for real:
[image]

Comment: I believe this might just be a way for Chrome to show long strings. As in all 30 numbers are there but since the string is too long its just shortening it for easy viewing. Maybe you can run a split on `\n` and see the length of the array ? I think it should still have all 30 values.

Comment: @DevanshSharma This is not the case — see update at the end of my question.

Comment: Hmm... not really sure then. I'm actually not able to get anything trying this on Firefox. I just get an empty string. It might just be a quirk in the way vscode on web is designed, since it does seem to override some default browser behavior (like right click menu etc.).